# i18next dealing with multiple translation files nested namespaces

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

I'm having issues figuring out how to lazy load my translations with i18next.

Here's my setup:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    debug: NODE_ENV === 'development',
    defaultNS: 'translation',
    fallbackLng: false,
    fallbackNS: 'translation',
    keySeparator: false,
    lng: 'en',
    load: 'currentOnly',
    nsSeparator: '.'
  });
```

I have a folder structure like this:

```
├── src
│   └── pages
│       ├── customer
│       │   └── home.tsx
│       └── manager
│           └── dashboard.tsx
```

I keep my translations in `/public/locales/en/translation.json` and this works fine. However, my app is expanding and I don't want to keep all my translations for a language in single file. E.g. the `customer` doesn't need to download all the translations for things happening on the `manager` portal.

My goal is to download translations specifically for the manager's Dashboard.

I've tried creating a file and adding it to this location

> `/public/locales/en/manager/dashboard`

And then in my React component I make use of the following hook:

```
...
  // This probably needs to change
  const { t } = useTranslation('manager.dashboard');

  return <div>{t('Hello World')}</div>
```

And just to test it out my `/public/locales/en/manager/dashboard.json` (I really want to maintain this file structure) file has a single key value in it:

```
{ "Hello World": "Goodbye World" }
```

It's not working (works if I add this key to the `/public/locales/en/translation.json` file)

How can I change my configuration to get this organized nest translation file structure to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using useTranslation like that:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('manager.dashboard');
```

Your filename should be like this `/public/locales/en/manager.dashboard.json`

btw. when lazy loading make sure you use Suspense or check for the ready flag: https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense

You may also check out this page, regarding multiple translation files: https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files

edit: Alternatively, you can try with this:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('manager/dashboard');
```

like here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-http-example-forked-2ptmu?file=/src/app.js:153-162

Comment: So there's no way for me to use the file structure like this? `/public/locales/en/manager/dashboard.json`

Comment: Because I really want to main that folder structure and would only change that as a last resort.

Comment: Did you try with const { t } = useTranslation('manager/dashboard'); ?

Comment: Yeah, didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure? For me it works. Can you provide a reproducible example? maybe on codesandbox or similar?

Comment: Do you have a codesandbox example of it working?

Comment: What is your `init` configuration on your working version? Anything different to what I provided?

Comment: here we go: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-http-example-forked-2ptmu?file=/src/app.js:153-162

Comment: Thanks, looks like my problem was I didn't have `interpolation: { escapeValue: false }`, after adding that it started working!

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for this. I was pulling my hair out

Comment: Does anyone have a working example for `next-i18next`? I have been trying to make it work, even using `interpolation: { escapeValue: false }`, in `next-i18next.config.js`, but it doesn't seem to load it.

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/tree/master/examples

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next#client-side-loading-of-translations-via-http

Answer (score 2):

As an option to an @adrai answer, if you don't want to disable `escapeValue` options in the `i18n` configuration, you can use double backslash in the hook:

`const { t } = useTranslation('common\\header');`

My folder structure is:

```
├── public
│   └── assets
│       └── locales
│           ├── common
│           |   └── header
│           │       ├── en.json
|           |       └── ua.json
│           └─ login
│              ├── en.json
|              └── ua.json
```

And in config I have this setting:

```
backend: {
  loadPath: '/assets/locales/{{ns}}/{{lng}}.json'
},
```